# RecyclerView Adapter Error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String RANK = "rank";
static String COUNTRY = "country";
static String POPULATION = "population";
static String FLAG = "flag";
// URL Address
String url = "http:";
public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String x = "/aaa/bbb/omer/000";
    String []tokens = x.split("/aaa/bbb/");
    for (String t: tokens)
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    listview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    listview.setLayoutManager(llm);
    new JsoupListView().execute();
    return view;
}

// Title AsyncTask
private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Diziler Yükleniyor");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            // Connect to the Website URL
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
            for (Element table : doc.select("div[class=col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pad0 middle]")) {

                // Identify all the table row's(tr)
                for (Element row : table.select("div[class=col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pad0 streamingBoxWrap mNewsItem]:gt(0)")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Identify all the table cell's(td)
                    Elements tds = row.select("a");

                    // Identify all img src's
                    Elements imgSrc = row.select("img[src]");
                    // Get only src from img src
                    String imgSrcStr = imgSrc.attr("src");

                    Elements aSrc = row.select("a[href]:gt(1)");
                    String aSrcStr = aSrc.attr("href");

                    // Retrive Jsoup Elements
                    // Get the first td
                    map.put("rank", aSrcStr);
                    // Get the second td
                    map.put("country", tds.get(1).text());
                    // Get the third td
                    map.put("population", tds.get(2).text());
                    // Get the image src links
                    map.put("flag", imgSrcStr);
                    // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

ListViewAdapter:

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        final TextView rank;
        TextView country;
        TextView population;
        ImageView flag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitemview, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
       // rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        //rank.setText(resultp.get(MainFragment.RANK));
        country.setText(resultp.get(MainFragment.COUNTRY));
        population.setText(resultp.get(MainFragment.POPULATION));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainFragment.FLAG), flag);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position

                resultp = data.get(position);
                DiziFragment myFragment3 = new DiziFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("gun",resultp.get(MainFragment.POPULATION));
                bundle.putString("flag",resultp.get(MainFragment.FLAG));
                myFragment3.setArguments(bundle);
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,myFragment3);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

[image]

Gradle build
[image]

I want to list items with recyclerview. Help me Please.

Turkish:kodda listview ile liteliyordu ben ise recyclerview ile listelemek istiyorum.

edit my code
adapter:

```
public class SimpleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public SimpleRecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}




@Override
public  RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

    final TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitemview, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    // rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    //rank.setText(resultp.get(MainFragment.RANK));
    country.setText(resultp.get(MainFragment.COUNTRY));
    population.setText(resultp.get(MainFragment.POPULATION));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainFragment.FLAG), flag);
    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position

            resultp = data.get(position);
            DiziFragment myFragment3 = new DiziFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gun",resultp.get(MainFragment.POPULATION));
            bundle.putString("flag",resultp.get(MainFragment.FLAG));
            myFragment3.setArguments(bundle);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,myFragment3);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

return itemView; is eroor
[image]

Comment: you are typecasting recyclerview to your adapter.

Comment: RecyclerView listview; is this ?

Comment: what did you put in fragment_main.xml? RecyclerView or ListView?

Comment: @Blackbelt <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recycler view then your adapter should also extends recycler view instead of Base Adapter. For eg.

```
    public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

        //Download image using picasso library
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(customViewHolder.imageView);

        //Setting text view title
        customViewHolder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example follow this link for complete implementaion